# Crash when nodejs socketio + passport authorization fails

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io, passport.js

I'm having an odd problem... I have a website running via nodejs. I have passport.io and socket.io being used together to allow users to have sessions and communicate back and forth with the server.

So my issue is that everything works fine for a user who is logged in via mongoDB user accounts... But if a user visits the site not logged in, it gives me the following error and the whole nodejs web server crashes.

> 2017-07-04T05:04:09.491294+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:61
>
> 2017-07-04T05:04:09.491309+00:00 app[web.1]:         fn = function () { throw arg; };
>
> 2017-07-04T05:04:09.491312+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onAuthorizeFail [as fail] (/app/server.js:97:11)

I'd like to know what's causing this to happen... how I can get better log information because the above info is pretty useless to me... and how I can fix this.

I want to be able to allow not logged in users to visit my site (and especially not crash it)

Comment: Might be a bug in `/app/server.js` line 97. Show us code so we can better help you.

Comment: Sure. The line is "throw new Error(message);"

It's the standard code used in many examples like this authorizefail function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477617/how-to-authenticate-socket-using-passport